# How to trace part of complex variable in WF?

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation, trace

Good day to community.

There is a workflow project with SQL Tracking enabled (like described in WF/WCF samples files, section Basic/Tracking/SqlTracking). I'd like to modify it to save variables in database not in XML Serialized view. Unfortunately, I have complex data in my WF project, including collections and nested objects.

When I modify system.serviceModel/tracking section in my web.config to save only listed variables, it works only for simple variables and does not look into objects.

As I read MSDN and TechNet articles, there are TrackingRecord class that holding information about those variables (in Variables property). How can I modify Variables forming block to fill it with parts of complex WF data? Is that possible?

Sorry for my English, I had no practice for years :(